# Reading from excel in C# .net windows server R2

Tags: c#, excel, windows-server-2012-r2

While reading from excel file on local environment using OLEDB works well. For doing this on a windows server it is required that we download OLEDB engine (MS Access engine 2010). This can be downloaded form:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

But this approach isn't working on Windows Server 2012 R2 even after downloading the required libraries.

Can someone help with this please?

Comment: Why are you using oledb to read an excel file?

Comment: The code was written about an year ago. When we tested it on our servers (which is most probably windows 2008 server ) after reqd. installation, it worked fine. Its giving trouble on client's server

Comment: Error message? Stack trace?

Comment: Is OLEDB being used for a database connection?

Comment: What is the error you are receiving.

Comment: No its been used to make an Excel connection. Connection string is: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;
Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";

Comment: This is not answerable without an error message/trace/description of why it does not work

Comment: Server...is this a console application or does this process originate from IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the 64-bit Windows server 2012 wan't able to read an xls file, even if Access database engine was present in it. It was able to read xlsx files though.

To resolve this, I went to application pool in IIS, and set the property of 32-bit applications "True" there. It started to work for both xls and xlsx files.